# PHP sorting arrays numerically by key value descending

Tags: php, arrays

Is there an option in PHP to sort an array by key value descending?

I am aware that you can sort key values with [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, the [krsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php)

```
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
krsort($fruits);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe [krsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Posting a hurried link to the documentation in after about sixty seconds of the ask time perfectly represents how FGITW answers were bad for Stack Overflow and its researchers during the early years.  This answer lacks generosity.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php krsort?

Comment: Posting a hurried link to the documentation in after about sixty seconds of the ask time perfectly represents how FGITW answers were bad for Stack Overflow and its researchers during the early years.  This answer lacks generosity.